# Implementing admob in xamarin android throws Java.Lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I'm creating an android application with xamarin and want to add ads using admob, I have already registered and created a banner unit so I have an app id and an ad id. I have implemented everything according to some guides but after I want to run it on my device it throws the following exception:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException
Message=Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: googl link to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: googl link.                           *
******************************************************************************
```

Here is the relevant part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
               android:value="ca-app-pub-myappid"/> <!-- I have my actual app id here -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
              android:exported="false" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <provider android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" 
              android:authorities="com.companyname.tapitmate.mobileadsinitprovider" 
              android:exported="false" 
              android:initOrder="100" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This is my adview class:

```
public class AdControlView : View
{
}
```

This is my view renderer:

```
public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdControlView, AdView>
    {
        //This is the test id according to the documentation
        private readonly string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        private readonly AdSize _adSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
        private AdView _adView;

        public AdViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        AdView CreateAdView()
        {
            if (_adView != null)
                return _adView;
            _adView = new AdView(Context);
            _adView.AdSize = _adSize;
            _adView.AdUnitId = _adUnitId;
            var adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            _adView.LayoutParameters = adParams;
            _adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
            return _adView;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdControlView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control is null)
            {
                CreateAdView();
                SetNativeControl(_adView);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my main activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext);// I have tried both ways, same exception.
            //MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "myactualappid");
            LoadApplication(new App());
```

I'm using:

- Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.1
- Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.396
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 71.1720.1

What am I doing wrong? Please help.
            }

Comment: Are you able to fix it..I have followed all instructions..still getting same error

Comment: What is the `googl link to add`? can you add the URL here?

Comment: @Prateek These are https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml & https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml (SO blocks these shortened URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have missed ExportRenderer

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdControlView), typeof(AdViewRenderer))]
```

In mainactivity the below line should go before Forms.Init line , you have added after Init

```
  MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
```

Your manifest should have `adUnitId` in the meta-data element within application element. Not sure about that since entire manifest has not been posted here. [Like here](https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob/blob/master/Sample/SampleMTAdmob.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.samplemtadmob">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="SampleMTAdmob.Android">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca­-app-pub-­3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
      <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Also

> Important
>
> To test the banner during the development google uses two Banner Id, one for Android > and the other for iOS. Use them then remember to replace them with your own IDs:
>
> Android: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
> iOS: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716

Try this nuget instead of implementing Renderers [marcojak/MTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob)

Comment: I did everything as written in your answer, it doesn't throw the exception anymore, but it still isn't working. It doesn't do anything, doesn't even hit the OnCreate method, just shows a white background and stops the debugging after a few minutes automatically without any error. I tried it with the given nuget too with the same result.

Comment: Nevermind, it works like this, it was just something with my visual studio, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you just have to remove that `MobileAdsInitProvider`:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" 
    android:authorities="com.companyname.tapitmate.mobileadsinitprovider" 
    android:exported="false" 
    android:initOrder="100" />
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary) does not even have it; therefore I'd assume you refer to an outdated example.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? The error message should at least be another; and it has to be initialized by code: `MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "ca-app-pub-...");`.

Comment: Its not even hitting that line...its just throwing error when loading the app

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i update ads to version 71.1720.1, rolling back to version 60.1142.1 solved this issue for me had to do the same to Xamarin.maps