# xamarin java.lang.runtimeexception: 'unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.mobileadsinitprovider

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm just updated my application (more than 1 year without any update) So I decided to move to : xamarin forms 5.0.0.2012

I use Firebase 119.7, downgrade to 119.6,119.5,119.4,119.1, 118.1,71.1601.4

and still the same problem.
xamarin java.lang.runtimeexception: 'unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.mobileadsinitprovider: java.lang.illegalstateexception:

I followed all the several configuration in the manifest in my class and it still doesn't work

I also created a blank shell project (the one coming with xamarin forms) and just add firebase.ads or google.playservice.ads and the same error occurs

here are the tip i already followed:
[Implementing admob in xamarin android throws Java.Lang.RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797473/implementing-admob-in-xamarin-android-throws-java-lang-runtimeexception)

Does any one have a clue?

I add a empty xamarin shell form app with just the add of the firebase nuget
all the info are followed but it crashs
https://github.com/refre/AdMonCrash

Comment: It seems that the method MobileAds.Initialize() is obsolote, you can try to add is:
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>` inside manifest/application

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT: unfortunatly not. This evening,I will create a github projet in order let other poeple try and see

Comment: If I use MobileAds.Initialize() in Mainactivity, I will have sampe problem, but this problem will disappear when I add  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>`

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I just added a link to my github. You'll see as soon as you add the firebase nuget, it crashs. Normally, the app must not crash if the code doen't  make any call to any fuction/class on the nuget package, but in this case, it does. Then I added the info in the manifest, it crashed again. (nothing has been written in the mainactivity like moblileads.initialize(). You can try out and change the appId (I'm not trying to make money via this problem)

Comment: It seems that you add AdUnitId value in APPLICATION_ID inside AndroidManifest.xaml. Try to add correct application id.

Comment: Sorry @CherryBu-MSFT sorry but i don't get the problem. I followed the insturction from  android itself  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml what do you mean by application ID? I followed all instruction from Xamarin/MS/android. Now I've change the adunit id by the test one from android. is it possible to make a pull request on my project. Regards

Comment: @Refre So did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem